# Make grid classes and pollute HTML or create page sections styles independently?

Tags: html, css, css-frameworks

I'm currently switching from using CSS-Frameworks to writing my own CSS. 
I need a grid for my webpage and I'm little confused what path to choose.

I'm going to use flexbox. What confuses me is that I have 2 options.

The first option is to make my grid behave like grid in Foundation or Bootstrap.
Make .row, .column etc. classes and use them in HTML.

eg:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column large-12">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column large-6">
    content
  </div>
   <div class="column large-6">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

But it will make my templates heavier and slightly more polluted.

The second option is to use semantic HTML with BEM notation and make styles for each section independently.
Eg:

```
<section class="first-section">
  Some content
</section>

<section class="second-section">
   <div class="second-section__element">
      content
   </div>
    <div class="second-section__element">
      content
   </div>
</section>
```

If I choose the second option then I'll have to write grid styles for each section on the website. More content = more repeating code because each block will need "row" and "columns" mixin.

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well; You can correct me. I had a similar challenge as you are currently. I was trying to make the modern css layout work as the hacks that frameworks did to traverse the hurdles of the dom and styling. However, you need to clear your mind and see the power which modern CSS holds. It renders frameworks for what they are - hacks.

Let's try to recreate the layout you have above with css grid and flexbox. You will realize that you do not need BEM to achieve what you are looking for. You will realize that there is no pollution of HTML rather the markup is cleaner, leaner and more effective while not losing out on the styling.

CSS Grid (one option. There are many ways of doing this. In less than 10 lines I have the same style as framework. HTML is clean and accessible)

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.one {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.one, .two {
  background: #a03;
}

.three {
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Full width container with some content</div>
<div class="two">Container two with content</div>
<div class="three">Container two with content</div>
```

option 2: flexbox

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: #b3ac03;
} 

.two, .three {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: #a03;
}

.three{
  background: #bc2dc2;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Full width container with some content</div>
<div class="two">Container two with content</div>
<div class="three">Container two with content</div>
```

Comment: Let me clarify: my question is not about how to do this particular markup. 
But about is it better to have some generic set of grid classes (.row .column etc.) like how it is done in frameworks, and use them all over the project.

Or create a CSS for each block independently = recreate grid-like functionality in every block on the site (probably using mixin).

Comment: Refactoring code is the way to go. I am sure you know that makes your files smaller and makes bug fixing easier. To answer your question, if you are using modern CSS like flex box and CSS grid, no you don't need to have those generic classes but if you are using the positioning CSS then I would advise that.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with the first round, as I dislike having to re-declare styles depending on where I am in the document. I can say this with some certainty, as a project I work on was originally developed by our client's developer and I make changes to it for testing purposes to determine profitability of UI/UX modifications.

Now I've never actually talked to their dev about this, but from what I see in the project is that he liked the idea of a responsive framework, but didn't want to have to deal with Bootstrap / Foundation / Bulma, so he built his own. Problem is that since he was the developer working on this project (alone, from what I can tell) there are occasionally places where he has to duplicate code from another component, and because of how the files are compiled later on he can't just use a `@extend` call because the item may or may not be available.

Really, use whichever method makes the most sense for what you are doing, but I'd caution you against writing your own CSS that effectively just copies what Bootstrap / Foundation / Bulma / A million others are already accomplishing.